RxJS returning empty observable doesn't call succesful Action
I have a Rxjs effect that looks like:
callApiPostSyncPushEffect$ = createEffect(() => {
      return this.actions$
          .pipe(
            ofType(SyncActions.callApiPostSyncPushPullAction),
            mergeMap((action) =>  this._syncService.syncPush(action.isBeta)
              .pipe(
                map(model => SyncActions.callApiPostSyncPushSuccessfulAction()),
                catchError(error => of(SyncActions.callApiPostSyncPushPullFailedfulAction()))
              )
            )
          );
      });

syncPush method looks like:
syncPush(isBeta: boolean): Observable<SyncPushResultModel[]>{
    
    if(isBeta) return  new Observable<SyncPushRequestModel[]>;

......
)

When isBeta tag is set to true, it return an empty observable which means it won't trigger callApiPostSyncPushSuccessfulAction. How do I change it so SyncActions.callApiPostSyncPushSuccessfulAction() is triggered even one syncPush returns an empty observable?
Is there a way I could skip calling _syncService.syncPush altogether and trigger SyncActions.callApiPostSyncPushSuccessfulAction if isBeta is set to false?

Maybe you're looking for tap() operator instead of mergeMap() or just map() that returns SyncActions.callApiPostSyncPushSuccessfulAction()?

to return an empty observable the emits something, you should use of for example of([]) or of(null)
if you want to call callApiPostSyncPushSuccessfulAction when is beta is false:
 if(isBeta) {
 // do what you want
}else{
   SyncActions.callApiPostSyncPushSuccessfulAction()
}

but I guess I am missing some context, why do you do mergeMap() ?
what should happen if isBeta is true or false?
is callApiPostSyncPushSuccessfulAction an observable?
